# Redirection To Action

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Need Help in following Problem. My problem is while getting the credential from angularjs to Action MVC it is working fine but View is not redirecting to the other ActionResult. Why? need solution
This is my View:

```
<body ng-app="LoginModule">
<div id="body" ng-controller="LoginController">
    <div>``
        <div>
            <label id="labels">User Name:</label> <input type="text" ng-model="User.UserName" />
            <br />
            <label id="labels">Password:&nbsp;</label> <input type="password" ng-model="User.UserPassword" />
            <br />
            <input id="buttons" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" type="button" ng-click="Login()" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is My js :

```
var loginModuel = angular.module("LoginModule", [])
loginModuel.controller("LoginController", function ($scope, $http) {
    alert("LoginController");
    $scope.Login = function()
    {
        alert("Login Function");
        var result = $http({ method: 'POST', url: '/Home/Login', params: { user: $scope.User } });
        result.success((function() {
            window.location.href = '/Doctor/DoctorPanel';
        }));
        alert($scope.User.UserName + "-" + $scope.User.UserPassword);
    }
});
```

and MVC Action is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    JObject json = JObject.Parse(Request["user"]);
    string userName = (string)json["UserName"];
    string userPass = (string)json["UserPassword"];
    User u = New User();
    u.User_Name = "Test";
    u.User_Password ="ABCD";
    if (u.Users_Name == userName && u.Users_Password == userPass)
    {
        return View("WelcomUser","Home");
    }
    return View("Index","Home");          
}
```

Comment: what is the response you are getting from your ajax call ? is that a 200 ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using forms authentication? At no point in your login are you setting an authentication cookie or anything so there are no credentials being established which would cause any redirection to just go back to the login.

Plus you aren't using the return value from your controller at all (it is returning HTML not a redirect), you are instead setting the window location to /Doctor/DoctorPanel which I assume doesn't allow anonymous access so you are getting redirected back to the login.

Answer (score 0):

Is your view name correct at " return View("WelcomUser","Home");" , also when "return View" is hit, does your developer tool console give you any message ? My best guess us your Angular script is failing to resolve the view location and thus fails, and then doesn't allow other view to load.